# Why elem.hasOwnProperty() is false

Tags: javascript, properties, event-handling, click

I have a click handler

```
e.addEventListener('click', this.Multiply, false);
```

and a function

```
this.Multiply = function () {
    APi.Multiply(this);
};
```

and simple Select element.
So this gets Select element

Why running

```
this.selectedIndex
```

gives value => 2

But running `this.getOwnPropertyNames()` throws error

or `this.hasOwnProperty('selectedIndex')` -> gives false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because selectedIndex is actually a property on the prototype of the HTMLSelectElement rather than an instance property. To do your test as you want you could try something like:

```
this.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('selectedIndex');
```

or

```
this.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty('selectedIndex');
```

You should get your expected result.

Of course that assumes that your instance of `this` is actually your selected element. Certainly given this HTML:

```
<select id="example"></select>
```

Running this javascript:

```
var el = document.getElementById("example");
console.log(el.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('selectedIndex'));
```

Would print true to the console.

Comment: I just faced an issue where in chrome event.hasOwnProperty('data') ->gave  true
and in FF event.hasOwnProperty('data') -> false 
That was same event from PostMessage. What's the reason of that?

Comment: If you mock up a fiddle that I can open in chrome and firefox to demonstrate your problem I'd be happy to take a look for you.

Comment: this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xgwcbexw/1/
I just need to run event listener function from the console. 
Then from iframe scope run postMessege and event.hasOwnProperty(data) 
result is different in browsers

Comment: Hmm that is really strange @vickk. It appears that Firefox defines data as part of the MessageEvent prototype. I would guess that because of this the hasOwnProperty is failing because it's expecting you to be looking on the prototype. Chrome doesn't appear to be forcing the issue on this. You could spend some time googling and try and work out why this is breaking and find an elegant solution. Or, if you just want a quick fix to make this work in both browsers you could change your test from a single hasOwnProperty to `(event.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('data') || event.hasOwnProperty('data'))`